# OnClick activating on page load/refresh

Tags: php, html

I have a link which, when the page is called or refreshed, runs.

As this is set to execute onclick, this should not be happening.

I had a sneaking suspicion that because I had left the path empty in `href` that it might be causing the issue, but adding in a file location does not change the outcome.

```
<a href="" onClick="<?php exec('sudo python /var/www/html/lightson.py'); ?>"><img src="lightm.png" width="128" height="128"></a>
```

Comment: why is anything relevant in your code for this question that's above the line `<a href="" onClick="<?php exec('sudo python /var/www/html/lightson.py'); ?>">`...?

Comment: Unless you are sure of the answer, tell my why it's not?

Comment: I'm assuming the code you want running is inside `lightson.py` which is not this file you pasted, if it is, I don't understand why you wouldn't just reload on click...

Comment: The script is being executed on page load and refresh.  It should only be executed when I click the link.

Comment: you mean `lightson.py`? please confirm that's a different page

Comment: I updated your question; the rest of the code is really irrelevant... I think, feel free to roll back though if you don't agree, of course... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: I would like to give some credit to @Chris as he's very well pointing out a key point [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36827753/2037924): *You are mixing client side and server side code here*. He also confirmed the fact about how PHP code would execute no matter what that I refer to as assumptions and guesses below, and have since turned out to be true, of course.

Below is my original answer:

---

I have no experience with the `exec` function, but somehow my gut feeling tells me it will execute no matter where it is in a HTML document. Actually, it's like any function with PHP, you don't actually need it to be formatted properly in an HTML file, it will run anyway (well, unless it's commented out), so that's the reason it calls every time, I guess...

Best if you use AJAX instead or some other means to load your external file, not a PHP call (server), considering you're using `onclick` that returns the click event handler code (client).

Example:

```
<a href="" onClick="myFunc()"><img src="lightm.png" width="128" height="128"></a>
```

The AJAX call:

```
function myFunc() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/var/www/html/lightson.py",
    // rest of the AJAX magic
  });
}
```

Comment: Well I understand why it was running on page load now.  But doing this with AJAX would mean I would need to write more code in the Python file to listen on ports for web handlers blah blah so not really the best way for me but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing client side and server side code here. **All** PHP will be evaluated whenever your page is rendered (unless there is a control structure like an `if` statement to stop it from being).

You can only put JavaScript in an `onclick` event. If you want to trigger server side code when an element is clicked you need to use AJAX.

Comment: I was about to type my answer when I saw yours posted, it's almost exactly the same, except I made some assumptions, that actually turned out to be true... :)